# Apply Css to the current button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to change the background color for three buttons using Javascript. Below is the code:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Box 1" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Box 2" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Box 3" onclick="changeColor(this)">

<script>
    function changeColor(this) {
        this.document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```

It works well for first button(Box 1).

When I click the second and third buttons, the background color of first button changes.

But I need to change the background colors of respective buttons that I have clicked.

Can anyone please help me to know where I was wrong?

Comment: Having more than one element with the same ID is invalid HTML. You should fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `this` as a variable name causes a Javascript error, since `this` is a reserved keyword. Change `this` to the button variable (`element` in the snippet below) and pass it to your function.

Also - **never set the same ID for multiple elements!** This renders as an **invalid HTML** document.

Here's a working code snippet:

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Box 1" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Box 2" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Box 3" onclick="changeColor(this)">

<script>
    function changeColor(element) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using same `id` for all the buttons. Use `class` instead.

Also, `this` is a reserved keyword and since you're using it as parameter name causes an error.

```js
function changeColor(elem) {
   elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 1" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 2" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 3" onclick="changeColor(this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `this` into your param with whatever you want. Because `this` is a keyword which represents a context. Here it is `window` object.

```
function changeColor(element) {
   element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you. Take a note of this and move forward! ;)

Answer (score 2):

`id` need to be unique also in the function `changeColor` , this as an argument may not be relevant, you can provide any other name. In the function the argument `elem` will represent the context which has triggered the click event.
The the id from it and change it's style

```js
function changeColor(elem) {
  this.document.getElementById(elem.id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Box 1" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Box 2" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="Box 3" onclick="changeColor(this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is always referencing the element with the `id` of `btn`, which all three of your inputs have.

Where you are passing `(this)` into your function, you should instead pass in the button's id.

In your function, you can then reference the id that was passed in:

```js
    function changeColor(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

Then, just change your onclicks to something more like `onclick="changeColor('btn1')"`.

You may also want to consider adding a class to the element, as opposed to adding inline styling. This gives you more flexibility:

```js
    function changeColor(id) {
        let btn = document.getElementById(id);
        btn.classList.add('red-button');
    }
```

Then just add some CSS:
`.classList {
  background-color: red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `id` to `class` because `id` has to be unique.

Try it like this:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 1" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 2" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 3" onclick="changeColor(this)">

<script>
    function changeColor(this) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet with 2 different solutions, the one you wanted to achieve, and a better one, where I suggest you to not use inline Javascript:
(See comments in my code)

```js
function changeColor(elm) { // "this" is reserved keyword, changed to "elm"
  elm.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // No need for getElement here, we already have it, it's "elm"
}


// Better solution: for no use of inline JS, do the following :
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- I guess this one is waht you wanted to achieve -->
<input type="button" value="Box 1" onclick="changeColor(this)">
<!-- Changed id to class for the 2 next, to make it work without inline JS -->
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 2">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Box 3">
```

Hope it helps.